# Make one part of stack scroll over another part

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to achieve relatively simple looking effect, I want to have a red background on the top and make the white container beneath it scrollable over it and have the rest of the screen in the white part, there's probably some easy solution for that, but I couldn't think of any.

[image]

```dart
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(250, 250, 250, 1),
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        children: [
         
             Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              color: Colors.red,
            
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 250),
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(250, 250, 250, 1),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(48),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(48))),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you've tried so far?

Comment: Also can you include an image what are you trying to archive?

Comment: Ok hope I;ve got it

Comment: I was also thinking about using a Parallax effect, which would make the red part freeze, but I wouldn't be able to stack them if I did so, also, as this is pretty common thing, I think there will be way simpler solution 

Answer (score 0):

You can use `backgroundColor:red` in this case.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 200,
        ), // your widgets here/ or just top level space
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(250, 250, 250, 1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(48),
                topRight: Radius.circular(48)),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Perhaps you need [`CustomScrollView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) for more effect. Follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YY-_yrZdjGc)

```dart
class OverlayFX extends StatelessWidget {
  const OverlayFX({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
                pinned: true, // change if needed
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                expandedHeight: 150.0,
                flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  title: Text('Available seats'),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle),
                    tooltip: 'Add new entry',
                    onPressed: () {/* ... */},
                  ),
                ]),
            SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate.fixed([
              ColoredBox(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(250, 250, 250, 1),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(48),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(48))),
                  height: 6500,
                  width: constraints.maxWidth,
                ),
              )
            ]))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about this already, but I would like to use BouncingScrollPhysics on the SIngleChildScrollView, with this approach the bottom aprt will be red when "bouncing", is there some way to make the actual widget bigger than the scrollable part?

Comment: For that case, It will be better handle red color on 1st child.

Answer (score 0):

Try draggableScrollableSheet

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
          builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.blue[100],
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: scrollController,
                itemCount: 25,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It also has minChildSize in which you can set the minimum size required and it will be draggable and will take up all space if required